# another way to verify unix wait is completely finished with process

Tags: shell, unix, parallel-processing, logic

I'm firing off two processes in the background. How can I absolutely guarantee `wait $pid2 $pid3` is working and will wait for completion before firing off 3.sql?  I cannot fire off 3.sql until making sure 2.sql is completely done.
Can someone show me another technique for checking this?

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
1.sql
2.sql &
3.sql &
pid2=$!
pid3=$!
wait $pid2 $pid3
4.sql
```

Comment: If you need sequential behaviour, then why not run them in the foreground?

Comment: Your text says you want 3 to wait for 2, but your code has 4 waiting for 2 and 3 (assuming you fix the script you show and define `pid3`). Can you clarify? Also, is there a reason you think that the `wait` won't work?

Comment: The sequence is to run 1.sql first and for that to complete. Then I need 2.sql, 3.sql to run in parallel to speed up things, but I just need to make sure they both finish before firing off 4.sql. Maybe i'm asking for a way to log this and make sure both those are done before lastly firing off 4.sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you are currently using seems legitimate. If for some reason you do not trust the operating system or the shell, you could make the scripts print some output once they're done, and capture that output - for example:

```
rm -f 2.out 3.out
2.sql > 2.out &
3.sql > 3.out &
...
wait $pid2 $pid3
if [ "$(cat 2.out)" != "done" ] || [ "$(cat 3.out)" != "done" ]; then
    echo "2.sql and 3.sql didn't really finish - exiting" >&2
    exit 1
fi
4.sql
```

(You could turn `if` and `exit` into a `while` with a short `sleep`, which would remove the need for `wait` in the first place.)

Comment: this is what i was looking for. adding one more check.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the entire script, you can simplify it by doing a plain `wait`:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
1.sql
2.sql &
3.sql &
wait
4.sql
```

If you want to wait explicitly, you need to set the pids correctly.  You're waiting for `3.sql` only because you run `2.sql` in the background but don't collect its pid before running `3.sql` in the background.  You should have:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
1.sql
2.sql &
pid2=$!
3.sql &
pid3=$!
wait $pid2 $pid3
4.sql
```